# Calculate number of consecutive months an ID occurs in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

Looking for a solution using Power Query to find the number of consecutive months that an ID in a row.

This is the expected output where column "Times" is the desired column:

| ID | Date | Total | Times |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 202301 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 202302 | 20 | 0 |
| A | 202303 | 20 | 0 |
| A | 202304 | 0 | 1 |
| A | 202305 | 0 | 2 |

When grouped to pull the total consecutive times it appeared in data:

| ID | Latest Consec |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |

So that it only shows the latest total consecutive appearances.

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If so please mark as solved by toggling checkmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Table.AddColumn(
#"Renamed Columns",
"Times",
(r) => if r[Total] = 0
       then 1+List.Count(
                List.LastN(
                    Table.SelectRows(
                        #"Renamed Columns",
                        each [ID] = r[ID] and [Date] < r[Date]
                    )[Total],
                    each _ = 0 
                )
            )
       else 0
),
Table.Group(AddColumn, {"ID"}, {{"Latest Consec", each Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Descending}})[Times]{0} , type number }})
```

Solved with this and then grouping gives out the final desired results.  Addcolumn gives out the total times when total = 0 and finds when total = 0 and starts up the count from given date.
Only problem I have is that the addcolumn takes a while to load on a small dataset.

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, you can try this which groups, and within the groups, sorts by date and takes Times for latest date

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID"}, {{"Latest Consec", each Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Descending}})[Times]{0} , type number }})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]